# set_fact is not persisting

Tags: set, ansible, fact

I am using ansible 2.0.1 on RHEL 7 hosts. Somehow following roles when called through playbook skips the Get  the yellow major version.
Attaching output below. Looks like there is something wrong with the when condition.

---

```
  - set_fact: is_yos="true"

  - name: Fetch yellow version
    shell: /bin/gawk '{ for(col = 1; col <= NF; col++) if ($col ~ /[0-9.]+/) { print $col; } }' /etc/yellow-release
    register: yel_ver_str
    failed_when: false
    changed_when: false

  - set_fact:
      is_yos: "false"
    when: yel_ver_str.rc != 0

  - debug: var=yel_ver_str

  - debug: var=is_yos

  - name: Get yellow major version.
    shell: echo {{ yel_ver_str.stdout }} | awk -F. '{print $1}'
    register: yel_major_ver
    when: is_yos == "true"
    delegate_to: localhost
    changed_when: false
```

Output

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yml -c local

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [172.31.83.23]

TASK [test : set_fact] *********************************************************
ok: [172.31.83.23]

TASK [test : Fetch yellow version] *********************************************
ok: [172.31.83.23]

TASK [test : set_fact] *********************************************************
skipping: [172.31.83.23]

TASK [test : debug] ************************************************************
ok: [172.31.83.23] => {
    "yel_ver_str": {
        "changed": false,
        "cmd": "/bin/gawk '{ for(col = 1; col <= NF; col++) if ($col ~ /[0-9.]+/) { print $col; } }' /etc/yellow-release",
        "delta": "0:00:00.004225",
        "end": "2016-04-22 13:37:29.517570",
        "failed": false,
        "failed_when_result": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2016-04-22 13:37:29.513345",
        "stderr": "",
        "stdout": "7.2.0",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "7.2.0"
        ],
        "warnings": []
    }
}

TASK [test : debug] ************************************************************
ok: [172.31.83.23] => {
    "is_yos": true
}

TASK [test : Get yellow major version.] ****************************************
skipping: [172.31.83.23]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
172.31.83.23               : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: That shows that `yel_ver_str.rc == 0`, which is why your `set_fact` task is getting skipped.  That task will only run when `yel_ver_str.rc != 0`.

Comment: when condition for "Get yellow major version" is when: is_yos == "true" and not yel_ver_str.rc != 0.  Also i am setting up the default value for is_yos as true

Answer (score 0):

Look at this output from your `debug` task:

```
TASK [test : debug] ************************************************************
ok: [172.31.83.23] => {
    "is_yos": true
}
```

The `is_yos` fact is a *boolean* variable (`true` is a boolean value, while `"true"` would be a string value).  So when you test:

```
when: is_yos == "true"
```

The check is *false*, because you are comparing a boolean to a string.  Instead use:

```
when: is_yos
```